# vw.FTSearchSorted fails when specifying ascending sort order

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a FTSearchSorted issue

My code in some SSJS looks like this:

```
var vw:NotesView = thisAppDB.getView("vwFTSearch")
var n:Integer = vw.FTSearchSorted(qString, 0 , "SortBy" , false, false, false  );
```

And I get the error below

AfterPageLoad response MYActionView Method NotesView.FTSearchSorted(string, number, string, boolean, boolean, boolean) not found, or illegal parameters

If I change the code to:

```
var vw:NotesView = thisAppDB.getView("vwFTSearch")
var n:Integer = vw.FTSearchSorted(qString, 0 , "SortBy"   );
```

it runs without error. The first column in the view vwFTSearch is Sorted and is set to Click on Header to Sort = Both. If I open the view in Notes client I can click on the header and it sorts correctly. This returns the documents sorted Ascending by default, but I want it to be sorted Descending. Sure looks like it should work. Tried rebuilding the view index as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a seventh parameter `fuzzy:boolean` to FTSearchSorted:

```
var n:Integer = vw.FTSearchSorted(qString, 0 , "SortBy" , false, false, false, false);
```

Your FTSearchSorted call has to match to one of the following parameter versions:

```
FTSearchSorted(query:string) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:string, maxdocs:int) : int    
FTSearchSorted(query:string, maxdocs:int, column:string) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:string, maxdocs:int, column:string, ascending:boolean, exact:boolean, variants:boolean, fuzzy:boolean) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:string, maxdocs:int, column:int) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:string, maxdocs:int, column:int, ascending:boolean, exact:boolean, variants:boolean, fuzzy:boolean) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:java.util.Vector) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:java.util.Vector, maxdocs:int) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:java.util.Vector, maxdocs:int, column:string) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:java.util.Vector, maxdocs:int, column:string, ascending:boolean, exact:boolean, variants:boolean, fuzzy:boolean) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:java.util.Vector, maxdocs:int, column:int) : int
FTSearchSorted(query:java.util.Vector, maxdocs:int, column:int, ascending:boolean, exact:boolean, variants:boolean, fuzzy:boolean) : int
```

You can find a full description of FTSearchSorted with examples [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_View_FTSearchSorted.html).